# App running in the background for 3 minutes

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, background

I have an app which maintains a socket connection with a server. When the application is backgrounded (Home button is tapped) this connection breaks, and when the user comes back reconnection takes around 5 seconds. Not too much, but still an annoyance.

This works perfectly, but I think I could improve the user experience if the app asked for background execution time with:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];
```

I get 3 minutes additional runtime here, and the socket can stay alive a little more. If the user returns in these 3 minutes then the there is no reconnection, the app can immediately be used again. (This happens quite often, because they just check their e-mail really fast, reply to a message etc... and immediately return to my app.)

This would definitely improve the user experience, and as I see some apps use this (like the IRC iOS client). The documentation clearly says though:

> You should not use this method simply to keep your app running after it moves to the background.

I don't want to run longer than 3 minutes or fake to be a VoIP or Music player app. This would just be a minor user experience improvement. Can Apple reject an app because of this?

(For now let's ignore that the socket connection doesn't break immediately when the app is backgrounded.)

Comment: Based on my experience, if they find out, then they'll reject your app. However app store review process is performed by a number of members YMMV. I'm not sure but think if you've never submitted to the app store before then they'll vet your app more vigorously than someone who's updated the app many times before without rejections. So *perhaps* you can update your in the later phases when Apple is less meticulous about you and your app :D. Curious what exactly do you in using the sockets? Is it of vital importance? If not I wouldn't bother...

Answer (score 0):

If appstore review team will find it, they will reject the binary. You have definite quote from documentation why you can't use it. Also, if you add background mode like your app is VoIP or Music player, but app is not such kind of application, it also can be rejected.